# Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

Tags: java, ssl, intellij-idea

I am in first in automated testing. So, I have a task to create automated script for API testing. I need to create https request with self-signed serificate. This certificate gave me our admins with p12 extension and password file. I exported this certificate to .cer extenssion. Than I created the trust store and import this certificate to this store.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin>keytool -import -keystore clienttrust.jks -file marta.cer -storepass storepass`

I located the marta.cer and clienttrust.jks near my project. I have writing my code in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1 on Java.

Here is code:

```
public void testSimpleHttpsClient() throws CertificateException, InterruptedException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        IOException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException {


    URL url = new URL("https://intstg1-kaakioskpublicapi.ptstaging.ptec/TLE/36171/player/info");

    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod( "GET" );

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    char[]  passphrase = "storepass".toCharArray();
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("clienttrust.jks"), passphrase);
    System.out.println(ks);

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(ks);

    System.out.println(tmf.toString());

    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {

        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
            return s.equals(sslSession.getPeerHost());
        }
    };
    con.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
   con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    InputStream inputStream;
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        inputStream = con.getInputStream();
    } else {
        inputStream = con.getErrorStream();
    }

    // Process the response
    BufferedReader reader;
    String line = null;
    reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        System.out.println( line );
    }

    inputStream.close();
}
```

So, after this code executes I get the next Exception:

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1471)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:936)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:871)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at httpConnection.Connection.testSimpleHttpsClient(Connection.java:179)
    at httpConnection.Connection.main(Connection.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValidator.java:384)
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:133)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1453)
    ... 20 more

Guys, please explain to me how to solve this problem.

Comment: have a look [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.jp/2014/06/authentication-with-client-certificate.html)

Comment: Ankur-singhal, thanks for your advice. I have a question to you. The entry type of my certificate is 'trustedCertEntry', but in your article - Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry. Is the ' Entry type' important very much?

Comment: The `HostnameVerifier` you're using is insecure. It's only checking the hostname against a reverse lookup (so vulnerable to MITM attacks), not against the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Import the server cert as trusted

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias somealias -keystore clienttrust.jks -file marta.cer